# Sumar elementos específicos de una lista de diccionarios con un condicionante

Tags: python

```
personas = [{'sexo':'masculino','edad':21},{'sexo':'femenino','edad':43},{'sexo':'femenino','edad':34},{'sexo':'masculino','edad':38}]
```

Me gustaría sumar las edades de las personas femeninas de esta lista de diccionarios.

Comment: Nada te impide hacerlo. Adelante! Muestranos lo que tienes avanzado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he acabado consiguiendo, por si alguien más tiene la duda:

```
edades = 0
for item in lista:
   if item['sexo'] != 'femenino'
      continue
   edades += item['edad']
print(edades)
```

Comment: Te faltan los 2 puntos `:` al final de la sentencia `if`

Answer (score 1):

Se que ya lo resolviste pero podrias hacerlo con menos codigo, te dejo como lo hice

lo que hice fue utilizar la funcion `reduce` importando el modulo functools esto bueno en js lo utilizas en cualquier array, despues de esto crear una funcion lambda para sumar los valores de edad, y la lista que se iteraria seria la lista creada por un filter

```
from functools import reduce
personas = [{'sexo':'masculino','edad':21},{'sexo':'femenino','edad':43},{'sexo':'femenino','edad':34},{'sexo':'masculino','edad':38}]

suma = reduce(lambda y,z: y['edad'] + z['edad'], list(filter(lambda x: x['sexo'] != "femenino", personas)))
```

todo en una linea y si lo ejecutas veras que te da el mismo resultado

Answer (score 1):

Por si lo quieres hacer en una sola linea:

```py
suma = sum([x['edad'] for x in personas if x['sexo'] == 'femenino'])
```